# How to test a drag and drop image upload function with playwright for angular

Tags: angular, playwright

I have an area in my angular application where my users can drag an image file from the PC to the webapplication.

```
  <div class="profile-logo-row-area">
    <div (fileDropped)="onLogoDroped($event)" appDragAndDrop class="container">
      <input #fileDropRef (change)="onFileSelected($event)" id="fileDropRef"
             type="file">
      <h3>Drop your logo here!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img [src]="transformedBase64()" alt="logo" class="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
```

On this Action the image file is uploaded and used as logo in the users profile.

I want to cover this with one single playwright test. How I can test drag&drop of an file into a specific drop area?